# how to Pass parameter with dynamic model class in Ntier MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

Firstly,

My controller code is ;

```
public ActionResult Menuler_Delete(int id)
        {
           Menuler val = general_service.getMenu(id);
            general_service.Delete(val);

            return RedirectToAction("Menuler", "Admin");
         }
```

My generalservice code is ;

```
public Menuler getMenu(int id)
        {
            MenulerService mservice = new MenulerService();

            return mservice.getMenu(id);

        }
        public void Delete( T model ) 
        {
            DbIslemler<T> islem = new DbIslemler<T>();
            islem.Delete(model);
        }
```

menulerservice code is ;

```
public class MenulerService
    {
        DbIslemler<Menuler> menuler_service = new DbIslemler<Menuler>();

        public Menuler getMenu( int id)
        {
           return menuler_service.Find(id);
        }

    }
```

my DBIslemler code is ;

```
public class DbIslemler<T> : IDbIslemler<T> where T : class
    {
 public void Delete(T model)
        {
            _database.Set<T>().Remove(model);
            _database.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Delete(object id)
        {
            T val = _database.Set<T>().Find(id);
            _database.Set<T>().Remove(val);
            _database.SaveChanges();
        }

public T Find(object id)
        {
           return _database.Set<T>().Find(id);

        }
}

namespace NTierMvc.DataAccess
{
    public class DataBase : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Popup> Popups { get; set; }

        public DbSet<New> News{ get; set; }

        public DbSet<Menuler> Menulers { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Now, I want to pass  **void Delete( T model )** value controller to general service. But my model class ( that's T ) changeable. Be Sometimes void Delete ( **Menu** model) , sometimes void Delete(**Popup** model) , sometimes void Delete(**News** model)

how can i do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Which value you want to pass?

Comment: upgrade my question ... Thanks.

Comment: Your code is not very clear for me, if you want to make a generic repository you should follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM

Comment: actually, ı create and use generic repository. My problem not in repository. ı have to pass dynamic repository class to delete function in general services. when ı was did , ı create generic repository with Type T and deleting model.  I dont know, maybe this can't be done.

Comment: As long as you have in your DbContext declare the DbSet<Menu>, and DbSet<Popup> and DbSet<News>, you Delete method must work. Can you post the DbContext ?

Comment: I create dbcontext.  Update question with dbcontext code.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying, you want to be able to pass any entity to `generalservice.Delete()`. You can do this simply by making the `Delete` *method* generic, you do not have to make the whole generalservice *class* generic:

```
public class GeneralService
{
    public void Delete<T>( T model ) 
    {
        DbIslemler<T> islem = new DbIslemler<T>();
        islem.Delete(model);
    }
}
```

I would say however that this doesn't look like good practice. You already have a `MenuService`, so why not use that to delete menu objects? `GeneralService` looks like an unnecessary layer in between your controller and services.

Comment: When ı write this , ı already changed the layer structure like you said . but I was curious. It could be possible? . ty for answer. I think this could be but how ? :))